# Inheritance a big confusion for me

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

In given program assume

```java
class Base {
    private void show() {
        System.out.println("Base");
    }

    public void add() {
        show();
    }
}
```

```java
class Child extends Base {
    public static void main(String... s) {
        Child c = new Child();
        c.add();
    }
}
```

here `add()` is directly accessible in child & through which we are accessing the private member function `show()` of `Base` class. Here there is only 1 JVM instance i.e of `Child` class and since private member are not inherited they are not in JVM instance of `Child` and JVM instance of `Base` does not exist (so that linking between them can be done).
**Hence it is proves that they are inherited in child class!!! please explain this.**